# É possivel enviar valores do giroscópio e de uma seekbar simultâneamente via bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Olá, pessoal!

Estou tentando controlar um Drone (Hubsan X4) via sensores do smartphone. Porém não consigo enviar os valores coletados do giroscópio e de uma seekbar simultaneamente. A seekbar representa a velocidade (throttle) e o giroscópio é o controle direcional do drone.

Apenas consigo enviar um dos dados (ou giroscópio ou da seekbar), quando implemento os dois códigos o bluetooth envia apenas os dados do giroscópio que esta no onSensorChange() e a programação da seekbar está no onCreate().

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Desde já agradeço a atenção dispensada!

Comment: Poste o código para facilitar. Uma observação: Não sei se aplica a sua situação, já tive esse problema porém com Arduino e comunicação RXTX. A solução foi mandar os dados dos sensores um de cada vez, a diferença de tempo era pequena que era "quase simultâneo".

Comment: Oi @Daniela, eu estou realizando algumas mudanças no código e pretendo testar essa semana ainda. Assim que eu terminar postarei dizendo se obtive êxito ou não.

Desde já agradeço a sua ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

@Daniela, eu estava enviando como vc sugeriu (um de cada vez), porém como o envio dos dados dos sensores estavam no onSensorChange() e o envio dos dados da seekbar estava no onCreate() não era possível enviá-los simultaneamente. Como ainda sou novo nesse tipo de desenvolvimento não sabia que não poderia colocar tudo no onOnSensorChange(). Mas posso :) Por fim, concatenei todos os valores em uma string, converti para um vetor bytes e agora esta funcionando perfeitamente :) Veja o código:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    byte[] vetor;
    String eixoX, eixoY, eixoZ; // em GRAUS.
    String pacote = "";

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        gravity = event.values;
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        geomagnetic = event.values;
    if (gravity != null && geomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean sucesso = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, gravity,
                geomagnetic);
        if (sucesso) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            orientation = SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);

            eixoX = (int) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]);
            eixoY = (int) Math.toDegrees(orientation[1]);
            eixoZ = (int) Math.toDegrees(orientation[2]);

            // Envia para o arduíno
            if (mConnectedThread != null) {
                try {

                    // INÍCIO - SEEKBAR

                    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                            // velocidade.setText(progresso);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                                int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
                            // sensorStop = true;
                            velocidade.setText(Integer
                                    .toString(progressValue));

                        }

                    });

                    // FIM - SEEKBAR

                    // Velocidade
                    pacote += "V" + velocidade.getText() + "|";

                    // Envia 
                    pacote += "X" + eixoX + "|";

                    // Envia Y
                    pacote += "Y" + eixoY + "|";

                    // Envia 
                    pacote += "Z" + eixoZ + "|";

                    mConnectedThread.write(pacote.getBytes());
                    Thread.sleep(20);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "Erro ao enviar os dados via bluetooth",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }

            }

        }

    }

}@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    byte[] vetor;
    int eixoX, eixoY, eixoZ; // em GRAUS.
    String valorX, valorY, valorZ; // em BYTES.
    String pacote = "";

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        gravity = event.values;
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        geomagnetic = event.values;
    if (gravity != null && geomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        boolean sucesso = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, gravity,
                geomagnetic);
        if (sucesso) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            orientation = SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);

            eixoX = (int) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]);
            eixoY = (int) Math.toDegrees(orientation[1]);
            eixoZ = (int) Math.toDegrees(orientation[2]);
            xCoor.setText("X: " + eixoX);
            yCoor.setText("Y: " + eixoY);
            zCoor.setText("Z: " + eixoZ);

            // Envia para o arduíno
            if (mConnectedThread != null) {
                try {

                    // INÍCIO - SEEKBAR

                    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                            // velocidade.setText(progresso);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                                int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
                            // sensorStop = true;
                            velocidade.setText(Integer
                                    .toString(progressValue));

                        }

                    });

                    // FIM - SEEKBAR

                    // Velocidade
                    pacote += "V" + velocidade.getText() + "|";

                    // Envia X
                    //valorX = Integer.toString(eixoX * 256 / 360);
                    //pacote += "X" + valorX + "|";

                    // Envia Y
                    valorY = Integer.toString(eixoY * 256 / 360);
                    pacote += "Y" + valorY + "|";

                    // Envia Z
                    valorZ = Integer.toString(eixoZ * 256 / 360);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(valorZ) > 50)
                        valorZ = Integer.toString(50);
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(valorZ) < 0)
                        valorZ = Integer.toString(0);

                    pacote += "Z" + valorZ + "|";

                    mConnectedThread.write(pacote.getBytes());
                    Thread.sleep(20);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "Erro ao enviar os dados via bluetooth",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```